# What does the volitional for do in this sentence: 今までリーゼには見せたことの無いであろう優しい目

Tags: grammar

Sentence:

> 今までリーゼには見せたことの無いであろう優しい目をして微笑ほほえむと、カイルはリーゼを抱きしめた。リーゼも素直に身体を預ける。

My attempt of translation of the said part:
Smiling with kind eyes Rize never displayed so far

Answer (score 3, accepted):

「**～～であろう**」 expresses the speaker's ***inference***.  It is not volitional in meaning.

The more modern and colloquial form is 「**～～だろう**」, which you should be more familiar with.

> 「今{いま}までリーゼには見{み}せたことの無{な}いであろう優{やさ}しい目{め}をして微笑{ほほえ}む」

thus means:

> "**(Kyle) smiled with the gentle eyes that it was likely that he had never shown to Rize**."