# Meaning of さもあろう

Tags: grammar

In *Mushibugyou* there is this sentence:

> 実物の蟲もさもあろうというリアルな夢だな

The speaking character sees a giant mosquito (giant insects are common in the setting), thinks to be in a dream, and that he says that sentence; while I guess it means something along the lines of "It's a realistic dream, an insect close to the real thing", I can't understand what もさもあろうという means; I tried looking online and on my grammars, but while I found [some construction with さも](https://hinative.com/questions/19945868), I'm not sure it's the same thing, and how that construction works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, さもあろう is can be considered as a variant of さもあらん or さもありなん.

さ (然 in kanji) is an archaic equivalent of そう ("so", "this way") in modern Japanese. も is a particle.

- [Meaning of さすれば as a verb](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/43301/5010)

あろう is the "volitional form" of ある. A volitional form can have an inferential meaning, although this usage is becoming old-fashioned.

- [がな and ておろうな at the end of sentence parts](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/63091/5010)
- [What does the volitional for do in this sentence: 今までリーゼには見せたことの無いであろう優しい目](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/53432/5010)
- [Has Japanese syntax changed between the 1950s and today?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/94644/5010)

  > > 明日は雨が降りましょう。
  >
  > This was common in weather forecast until the 1970's, but we never hear this today.

なん in ありなん is explained in this question:

- [What's な doing in 絶えなんとする?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/92851/5010)

All in all, あるだろう, あろう, あらん and ありなん all have a similar meaning.

Practically, [さもあらん](https://jisho.org/word/%E7%84%B6%E3%82%82%E3%81%82%E3%82%89%E3%82%93) and [さもありなん](https://jisho.org/word/%E7%84%B6%E3%82%82%E3%81%82%E3%82%8A%E3%81%AA%E3%82%93) should be learned by rote as a set phrase without worrying about its archaic grammar. さもあろう is not really a common set phrase, so you have to get used to the inferential usage of the (よ)う-form, which is a little old but still part of the modern grammar.

Comment: I'm still not sure about the sentence as a whole: if さもあらん means "it's probably so", does it mean "It's a realistic dream with also an insect that was probably (like) the real thing"? I'm not sure about the sentence structure, and its general meaning.

Comment: @Mauro The sentence means, "This dream feels so realistic that it makes me think that even real 蟲 must be like this". So it looks like this speaker hasn't seen a real 蟲 yet. Does this match the story?

Comment: It does, thanks.